# Creating a function similar to subtotal, that ignores hidden columns

Tags: excel, vba, function, hidden, subtotal

I am trying to find a replacement for subtotal or aggregate that will sum all cells in a range except those whose column is hidden. Absent the presence of a builtin function I am trying to create my own but am having a lot of difficulty. I have tried the following VBA code but to no avail:

```
Function VISSUM(myRange As range) As Double
On Error Resume Next

Dim i As Variant
Dim mySum As Integer

For Each i In myRange
    If myRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) = True Then
        mySum = mySum + myRange
    End If
Next i

VISSUM = mySum

End Function
```

and this didn't work either:

```
Function mySum(myRange As range) As Double
On Error Resume Next

mySum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(myRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) = True)

End Function
```

I've also messed around with using `myRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = False` but no success there. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use the subtotal `mySum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, myRange)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always try:

```
i.entirecolumn.hidden = False
```

myrange would be checking everything hidden and not hidden, where as I should be the individual range you're dealing with either hidden or not.

Answer (score 1):

### Sum Up Columns

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Function VISSUM(ByVal myRange As Range) As Double

    Dim crg As Range, mySum As Double

    For Each crg In myRange.Columns
        If crg.Hidden = False Then
            mySum = mySum + Application.Sum(crg)
        End If
    Next crg

    VISSUM = mySum

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jonathan, that worked and i don't know how i missed that obvious mistake. this was what I ultimately wrote.

```
Function VISSUM(myRange As range) As Double
On Error Resume Next

Dim i As Variant
Dim mySum As Double

For Each i In myRange
    If i.EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
        mySum = mySum + i
    End If
Next i

VISSUM = mySum

End Function
```